# Am I correct that in 14.01 partman cannot move or copy partitions?

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, partitioning, system-installation

I am installing Dual-boot Ubuntu 14.04 on a new offer of HP, an HP110-220z AMD-64 architecture. It looks to be the 2014 standard entry level Computer.  The 500 GB hard drive has four partitions, but Partman displays more information than Windows Drive Manager. Note: portions in brackets [] are from the Windows Drive Manager (WDM) display.

- Free space 1 MB
- /dev/sda1 NTFS 1072 MB    [1023 MB recovery partition]
- /dev/sda2 EFI  377 MB     [EFI System partition]
- /dev/sda3 Unknown  134 MB [Not listed in WDM]
- /dev/sda4 NTFS 482995 MB [449.82 GB C:/ Boot, page file, crash dump]
- /dev/sda5 NTFS 15552 MB   [D:/ OEM Recovery Image]
- Free space 5 MB

sda5 is also customers copy of Windows 8.1, also NTFS and a Windows D:/ drive. Therein
   lies the problem. Having gone through the pain of making a USB NTFS
   boot-able drive and backing up Windows, I am suspicious that Microsoft
   still hasn't got it right, or cares.

And yes, this is how HP partitioned it.  I assume the free spaces are because HP aligned partitions on the even MB boundaries. 
What is interesting and scary is that the Windows Drive Manager does not recognize or list these portions of free space.

1. To create space for Ubuntu it has to come out of C:/. Partman handle
   this just fine. Even confirmed it in Windows Disk Manager after
   rebooting.
2. If Partman cannot move or copy D:/ this leaves the only
   place for the Ubuntu partitions between C:/ and D:/. With 30 years
   of DOS and Windows experience, I find that a very troubling
   scenario.
3. Partman has a screen display with buttons in 14.01 but the
   change button and the Edit Partition dialogue it invokes does not
   include any options for moving or copying. Nor can I find any notes
   in any documentation to date other than for earlier Ubuntu versions.
4. If both HP and Toshiba are partitioning hard disks this way I can
   only assume other computer manufactures are too. And that this will
   be a common challenge for any one wanting to add Ubuntu to a new
   computer.

I am documenting this install for the purpose of at least submitting it to the documentation group as a case study on a 2014 machine. Current documentation is one size fits all years and I hope I can help reduce that confusion. To do that I would appreciate your help here. A few answers would also help me in composing a bug report about these features.

1. Is Debian then what I should use and recommend. I have been studying documentation. There is no doubt of its robustness and dangers for the less than expert installer.
2. Or am I just not finding the way to the Move or Copy functions in the
   version of Partman that is loaded by the Ubuntu installer?
3. Are my fears of leaving a HPFS recovery D:/ partition out beyond the Ubuntu
   partitions and the problems of accessing it using the manufacturers
   DOS based utilities real?
4. Help me to know which parts of this complex question need to be asked where and if any, what bug reports are needed.